# using // instead of https:// or http:// to extract urls from a text

Tags: php, regex

**hello,**
im using [Embera](https://github.com/mpratt/Embera) (depending on Oembed)

the problem is this

```
 protected $urlRegex = '~\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))~i';
```

Embera just understand http or https, how i can make it supports //
like that`//youtube.com/watch?v=J-iyznGQ`

or i want a php regex function fix and url with // to http://

Comment: I would just add http(s):// if its not there.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(?:https?:)?//[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: @UnixMan, you still need to prefix and suffix the regex with `~`. vsk was just posting the body of the regex without the delimiters.

Comment: A note on delimiters, I've come to find that `(` and `)` work rather well, so far as escaping is concerned; as in, you needn't escape them in groups. Cleans up the syntax quite a bit.

Comment: how can fix this //youtube.com/watch?v=J-iyznGQ to https://youtube.com/watch?v=J-iyznGQ

Comment: @UnixMan make `//` `//?`